# Why the PySpark Dataframe's data gets shuffled when I save it as a parquet file?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I was trying to solve a problem related to PySpark Dataframe operations but every time it used to fail certain test cases. So I decided to check one by one and I found that when the data was retrieved from the parquet file that was created during the solution, then it is not in the order in which it was saved. I am adding my code below and also attaching the screenshots of failure causes and data frames. Please help with this.`# Put your code here

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.sql import *

from pyspark.sql.types import *

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Netflix analysis").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()

columns=["ID","Name","Age","Area of Interest"]

data=[("1","Jack",22,"Data Science"),("2","Luke",21,"Data Analytics"),("3","Leo",24,"Micro Services"),("4","Mark",21,"Data Analytics")]

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

df=rdd.toDF(columns)

df.coalesce(1)

df.show()

dfnew=df.describe("Age")

dfnew.write.parquet("Age")

dfnew.coalesce(1)

dfnew.show()

df2=df.select("ID","Name","Age").orderBy("Name",ascending=False)

df2.write.parquet("NameSorted")

df2.coalesce(1)

df2.show()

parDF1=spark.read.parquet("NameSorted")

parDF2=spark.read.parquet("Age")

parDF1.show()

parDF2.show()
```

[image]

This was the error shown to me

[image]

This is what I got when I tried to check what was happening. The first table is the one that I saved and the second table is the when which i got when i read it from the saved parquet file.